# How to sort multiple foreach from laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 different tables data has `order_id` and I want to sort it in laravel blade foreach.

My Controller:

```
$questions = Question::where('quiz_id', $quiz->id)->orderBy('order_id', 'asc')->get();
$explanations = Explanations::where('quiz_id', $quiz->id)->orderBy('order_id', 'asc')->get();
```

My Blade: (I want to sort this 2 foreach by order_id)

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
  <p>{{$question->title}}</p>      
@endforeach
@foreach($explanations as $explanation)
  <p>{{$explanation->title}}</p>
@endforeach
```

My Result:

```
<p>First Question</p>  //order_id: 1
<p>Second Question Question</p> //order_id: 3

<p>First Explanation</p>  //order_id: 2
<p>SecondExplanation</p> //order_id: 4
```

Result I Want:

```
    <p>First Question</p>  //order_id: 1
    <p>First Explanation</p>  //order_id: 2
    <p>Second Question</p> //order_id: 3
    <p>Second Explanation</p> //order_id: 4
```

Comment: Do you need to combine the results and show them? I mean to show the question with the explanation

Comment: could you explain more so we can help

Comment: not combining the result. it's not relations. maybe mixed the 2 foreach and sort by order_id.

Comment: @AissamAmezaourou sorry. I edit my question.

Comment: use array merge to merge 2 array questions and explanation. After merge, use usort - Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

Answer (score 0):

in the controller use toArray() and use array merge to merge the two arrays and sort them in the controller

Answer (score 0):

try this if it works:

```
@for($i = 0; $i <= $questions - 1; $i++)
  <p>{{$questions[$i]->title}}</p>
  <p>{{$explanations[$i]->title}}</p>    
@endforeach
```

or use `jsondecode()` to convert questions and explanations to array then:

```
@for($i = 0; $i <= $questions - 1; $i++)
    <p>{{$questions[$i]['title']}}</p>
    <p>{{$explanations[$i]['title']}}</p>    
@endforeach
```

This would only work if the number of questions and explanations are same.

Answer (score 0):

If in the explanation there is a question id then You can join the table and u can get easily get what you want.

or Maybe this thing can work for you.

```
@foreach($questions as $qKey => $question)
   @foreach($explanations as $aKey => $explanation)    
   @if($qKey == $aKey)
      <p>{{$question->title}}</p>
      <p>{{$explanation->title}}</p>
   @endif
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```